# Can not reflect changes in model

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS controller like this

```
var myModule = angular.module('test', []);

myModule.controller('PendataanMainController',
  function($scope, $http)
  {
    $scope.stat1 = "";
    $scope.stat2 = "stat2";

    $scope.AmbilStat1 = function()
    {
      $scope.stat1 = "Hallo stat1";
    };

    $scope.AmbilStat2 = function()
    {
      $scope.stat2 = "Hallo stat2";
    }



  }
);

myModule
  .directive(
    'fonloaded',
    function()
    {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
          var this_element = angular.element(element);

          this_element.bind(
            'click',
            function()
            {
              //this_element.html('<h2>Hallo dari directive</h2>');
              scope.stat1 = "Hallo dari directive";
            }
         );

          scope.$apply();

        }
      }


    }
  );
```

and a HTML like this

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="PendataanMainController" class="columns clear bt-space15">

  <div class="col1-2 fl-space2">

    <div class="content-box">
      <div class="box-body">

        <div fonloaded class="box-header clear">
          <h2>{{stat1}}</h2>
        </div>

        {{AmbilStat2()}}

        <div class="box-wrap clear">
          {{stat2}}
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="col1-2 lastcol">

    <div class="content-box">
      <div class="box-body">

        <div class="box-header clear">
          <h2>Stat 2</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="box-wrap clear">
          {{stat2}}
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I made a custom directive 'fonloaded' and put it on this part:

```
<div fonloaded class="box-header clear">
  <h2>{{stat1}}</h2>
</div>
```

and when it got clicked, the directive link function change the value of stat1. I want that new stat1 reflected in the html. But it don't.

I am using AngularJS extension for Chrome. And I can see that the stat1 value has changed, but that change does not reflected on the html.

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/4kiJwrG8Xo0unrNc9Fw7?p=preview

please see fixed sample:

```
function()
    {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
          var this_element = angular.element(element);

          this_element.on('click',
            function(e)
            {
              // alert('1');
              //this_element.html('<h2>Hallo dari directive</h2>');
              scope.stat1 = "Hallo dari directive";
              scope.$apply();
            } );
        }
      }


    }
```

Comment: Eugene, I have moved `scope.$apply();` as you suggested. And it still does not reflect the change in the model.

Comment: Eugene, I have changed the code as you suggested. And it still does not reflect the change in the model.

Comment: The problem you have faced is that I posted above. + Div which you marked as fonloaded is 0 height. So in fact you can't click on it, So in fact you can't that directive works. Please see updated sample. where I have added "EMPTY" string for visibility

Comment: Eugene, yes, I have considered about 0px height. So I tried to put static text like your 'empty'. But it still does not reflect the changes in the model. I confirmed the event triggered by putting `alert(1);`.

Comment: Eugene, I must add that I am working within a HTML template (like one from theme forest). I have striped the ng-app part out of the HTML template to make it stand alone. And now it reflect the changes in the  model. Now I wonder how this HTML template interfering the AngularJS?

Comment: Somehow the HTML template using jQuery to modify the <h2> tag which has fonloaded directive. As result {{stat1}} lost by HTML template transformation.

Comment: interesting note: html template can be , template of directive, or partial template in term of Angular.Js. if directive - define it on directive level, if partial - use ng-include, usually, or ng-view(but it's more complicated cases when you have set of routes)

Answer (score 0):

I must add that I am working within a HTML template (like one from theme forest). I have stripped the ng-app part out of the HTML template to make it stand alone. And now it reflect the changes in the model.

Somehow the HTML template using jQuery to modify the  tag which has fonloaded directive. As result {{stat1}} lost by HTML template transformation.